# Iterate from XML data and update the table

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table called `customer`, and I have the columns `id`, `sortcode`, and `name`.

I have one more table called `tblxml`, it has one column called `xmlData` of type CLOB and it stores the XML data.

I have stored XML data as follows:

```
 <root>
    <nd>
        <id>1</id>
        <sc>001</sc>
    </nd>
    <nd>
        <id>2</id>
        <sc>001001</sc>
    </nd>
    <nd>
        <id>11</id>
        <sc>001001001</sc>
    </nd>
    <nd>
        <id>16</id>
        <sc>001001001001</sc>
    </nd>
    <nd>
        <id>13</id>
        <sc>001001002</sc>
    </nd>
    <nd>
        <id>9</id><sc>001002</sc>
    </nd>
    <nd>
        <id>14</id>
        <sc>001002001</sc>
    </nd>
    </root>
```

I have aligned it so it is easy to understand.

I need to:

- extract this XML data from `tblxml` and update it in `customer`
  table.
- extract `Id` from `tblxml` table and update the `sortcode` in `customer` table which matches to id.
- loop the XML data in update the sortcode according to id.

I have used `<nd>` to separate the rows.

As I'm new to Oracle, I haven't tried coding for this. Expecting some suggestions.

Comment: Presumably your actual xml includes a root node? (eg. `<top><nd>..</nd>...<nd>..</nd></top>`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem.

- Created new Temporary table called **TMP_XML** it has one column as *hold_xml*
- Inserting xml content from *tblxml* to *TMP_XML* table
- Then extracting value from *TMP_XML* as follows and updating *sortcode* based on matched *Id*.

  ```
    Insert    InTo TMP_XML
    Select    XmlType(PkgCBDmlXml.ExtractNodeValues(xmlData, 'root'))
      From    tblxml; 

    update    customer 
       set    sortcode =  (   Select  ExtractValue(Value(E),'//sc') Sc_New
                              From TMP_XML A,
                              TABLE(XmlSequence(Extract(A.hold_xml, '//nd'))) E
                              Where ExtractValue(Value(E),'//id') = id     
                              )
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like `XMLTABLE` is what you're after:

```
with sample_data as (select '<root><nd>
    <id>1</id>
    <sc>001</sc>
</nd>
<nd>
    <id>2</id>
    <sc>001001</sc>
</nd>
<nd>
    <id>11</id>
    <sc>001001001</sc>
</nd>
<nd>
    <id>16</id>
    <sc>001001001001</sc>
</nd>
<nd>
    <id>13</id>
    <sc>001001002</sc>
</nd>
<nd>
    <id>9</id><sc>001002</sc>
</nd>
<nd>
    <id>14</id>
    <sc>001002001</sc>
</nd></root>' xdata from dual)
-- end of mimicking a table called "sample_data" containing your xml data. See the main SQL below:
select id,
       sc
from   sample_data sd
       cross join xmltable('/root/nd'
                           passing xmltype(sd.xdata)
                           columns id number path 'id',
                                   sc varchar2(10) path 'sc');


        ID SC        
---------- ----------
         1 001       
         2 001001    
        11 001001001 
        16 0010010010
        13 001001002 
         9 001002    
        14 001002001
```

Once you have the query to pull the results from the xml column, you can then use that as part of an update or merge statement to do the necessary updating. This is left as an exercise for you to do - there are plenty of examples in StackOverflow and Google! If you get stuck, feel free to update your question with what you've tried.

Comment: Thank you. it is mandatory to include <root> at the beginning and end of the XML data?

Comment: Yup, otherwise it wouldn't be valid xml!

Comment: It doesn't have to be called root, though, but you do need all the sets of nodes to be enclosed in an outer node. Unless, of course, each <nd> in your example is its own separate xml document?

Comment: no all the <nd> are in the same xml document. and i have added now the <root> at the beginning and at the end.